# Bootstrap Progress Bars load once in view

Tags: jquery, animation, view, progress-bar

i'm having some trouble when I try to make progress bars load one in view, I've used a code found in this web site, here it is:

HTML:

```
            <div class="progress-element">
                <p>HTML</p>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >                
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <p>CSS</p>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="65"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >                
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <p>JavaScript</p>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >                
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <p>Wordpress</p>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >                
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div><!-- End of progress-element -->
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.progress-bar {
    background: purple;
}

.progress-element {
    text-align: left;
}
```

JS:

```
        $(".progress-element").each(function () {
            $(this).waypoint(function () {
                var progressBar = $(".progress-bar");
                progressBar.each(function (indx) {
                    $(this).css("width", $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%");
                });
            }, {
                triggerOnce: true,
                offset: 'bottom-in-view'
            });
        });
```

Can someone tell me why this will not work? Thank you so much! :)